# SAP BO 4.1 Auditing without Universes

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

Morning all,

I have recently deployed Crystal Reports 2013 and Crystal Server 2013 in a test environment, as we are currently using the 2008 version of both products.

As this deployment is in a test environment; I am keen to implement and try out as much as possible to implement the best solution as possible.

One of the things I have enabled is Auditing. Once set-up I went looking for the best way to utilise this but everything seems to allude to needing a Universe creation tool (Information Design Tool) which I don't have and can't obtain, as our SAP products are provided via a third party and we don't have access to the BI Client Tools.

So I'm back to trying to figure this all out via custom Crystal Reports.... I've read plenty of articles, one which provided me with the links needed between the Database Tables, but there don't seem to be any articles on what tables etc to use.

Has anybody done this?

Thanks in advance for any help, I'm tearing my hair out at the minute!

Answer (score 1):

### Direct RBMS access

Have a look at the official SAP documentation (I'm using the BusinessObjects manuals, but information in them should apply to Crystal Server as well), more specifically the [Business Intelligence platform Administrator Guide](http://help.sap.com/bobip41?current=bobip42#section4) (SP doesn't really matter, auditing doesn't tend to change much within a major release).

There are two sections that are important for you:

- The *Auditing* chapter, more specifically the section regarding Audit events.
- The *Auditing Data Store Schema Appendix*, which contains all the detail regarding the audit schema you could need.

[image: database schema]

### Using a universe

Have a look at the SCN blog post [Unlock the Auditing database with a new Universe and Web Intelligence Documents for BI4.1](http://scn.sap.com/community/bi-platform/blog/2015/07/15/unlock-the-auditing-database-with-a-new-universe-and-web-intelligence-documents-for-bi41). It contains a download link to an `LCMBIAR` file which you can import into your BI4 environment, without the need for a universe client tool. There's also a webinar and documentation available. The prebuilt WebI documents should save you a lot of time.

Requirements:

- BI Platform BI 4.1 **Support Pack 5** or greater for the Web Intelligence Documents
- BI Platform BI 4.1.x for the Audit database to be queried

Instructions:

1. Download the content (take the highest build numbered zip file)
2. Import one of the five 'Universe' LCMBIAR files into your system using Promotion Management (it will go into *BI Platform Auditing* folder)
3. Import the Web Intelligence LCMBIAR file (it will go into *BI Platform Auditing* folder)
4. Edit the connection that is imported (in *BI Platform Auditing* folder) with the correct login credentials.
5. Open the Web Intelligence document *STA1 - Start here - Events over time.wid* as your starting point!

The only issue might be with step 4, where you need to edit your connection. I don't know if you'd be able to edit the imported connection through the Crystal Reports application?

Comment: Thank you :) I have had a look at the documentation, and the diagram you've attached, but I can't figure out what I actually need to create some useful reports.

I think I need to re-read the documentation!